# Objc Blocks and memory management

Tags: automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks, objective-c-2.0

I am setting up a block which gets called on a custom UIButton press. I am assigning the block to the UIButton instance in viewDidLoad().

```
- (void) viewDidLoad{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   _customBTN.block = ^{
     self.test = @"Something";
   }
}
```

Should I keep the block on the stack since the block can only get called on a button press and that means viewDidLoad() would be on the stack, and this can be considered performant/best practice ... or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Blocks don't stay on stacks (memory stack) and rather are copied (`Objc` objects referred inside block get a retain call (+1 `retainCount`) and scalar variables get copied) to heap when instantiated. It means when the line:

```
 _customBTN.block = ^{
     self.test = @"Something";
   };
```

is executed, *stack frame* created for `viewDidLoad` function got *popped* from the *stack*, `self` got a +1 `retainCount` and block was assigned to the block property `of _customBTN`, later on `when _customBTN` calls the block (on say button tapped event) the block is executed and it uses self and does what it does.

P.S. Its safe to use `weak` references to `self` when referring inside a block. `weak` wouldn't increase `retainCount` of `self` (which can lead to a retain cycles in worse cases).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this if there is no other choice. Also, do not use *self* in block. Create a week reference like this:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
```

And use it in blocks:

```
_customBTN.block = ^{
  weakSelf.test = @"Something";
}
```